# If statement not working as expected in checking input value

Tags: python

Trying to get my `if` to either allow the user to input a name or randomly choose but no matter what is entered it goes to the input of name?

Any ideas?

**Here is my snippet:**

```
import random
import os
names = "Balo", "Bandugl", "Baroro", "Cag", "Charoth", "Dugling", "Dulko", "Fangot", "Gormath", "Varth", "Ugort", "Ogong", "Tuli", "Corg", "Chau", "Korg", "Salath", "Wegia",        "Wecha", "Moroth", "Kangir", "Bethindu", "Duak", "Fagoot", "Penam"
rand_name = random.choice(names)

#Character creation (1)#
if input("Would you like to choose a name?: ") == "Y" or "y" or "yes" or "YES":
    print("")
    c1 = {"Name":input("Name: ")}
else:
    c1 = {"Name":rand_name}
print(c1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorted changed my if to if input(... is IN a list of accepted answers variable :)

Comment: @FallenAngel: the system won't let you spell "statement" correctly because a question with that title already exists so... just spell it incorrectly instead?

Comment: My bad, a mis-spelling. Re-edited for a better title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your line

```
if input("Would you like to choose a name?: ") == "Y" or "y" or "yes" or "YES":
```

You can not chain values like that, it will evaluated as follows

```
( input("Would you like to choose a name?: ") == "Y") or ("y") or ("yes") or ("YES")
```

in which case, `or ("y")` will return `True` since non-empty strings are all evaluated `True`

You must try:

```
if input("Would you like to choose a name?: ") in ["Y", "y", "yes", "YES"]:
```

then it will check if input is one of `"Y"`, `"y"`, `"yes"` or `"YES"` values

Or you can use [`str.upper()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) to make your option list less crowded:

```
if input("Would you like to choose a name?: ").upper() in ["Y", "YES"]:
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if input("Would you like to choose a name?: ").lower() in ("y", "yes"):
```

Answer (score 0):

You comparison is wrong.

`if input("Would you like to choose a name?: ") in ("Y", "y", "yes", "YES"):`

To understand your error:

```
>>> "a" == "Y" or "y"
'y'
>>> "Y" == "Y" or "y"
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use raw_input(2.7) input in 3

```
import random
import os
names = "Balo", "Bandugl", "Baroro", "Cag", "Charoth", "Dugling", "Dulko", "Fangot", "Gormath", "Varth", "Ugort", "Ogong", "Tuli", "Corg", "Chau", "Korg", "Salath", "Wegia",        "Wecha", "Moroth", "Kangir", "Bethindu", "Duak", "Fagoot", "Penam"
rand_name = random.choice(names)

#Character creation (1)#
if raw_input('Enter your name: ').upper() in ["Y" , "YES" ]:
    print("")

    c1 = {"Name":raw_input("Name: ")}
else:
    c1 = {"Name":rand_name}
print(c1)
```